# How to correctly put an if statement inside of another string

Tags: php, oscommerce

I am new to learning php and I am working on an ecommerce site for myself.

I am almost getting the code but can't seem to get this syntax right. What I am basically trying to achieve is to insert a class into a < li > tag IF is is a sub category in a list.

Apologies for my lack of knowledge, if anyone could correct this for me I would be very greatful...

So the origanal code is

```
$categories_string .= '<li><a href="';
```

Then i am trying to modify it by adding the class and a statement there e.g:

```
$categories_string .= '<li class="'if (tep_has_category_subcategories()) {         $categories_string .= ''; }'"><a href="';
```

but that's not it i know.. then i tried...

```
$categories_string .= '<li class="'if (tep_has_category_subcategories()) { echo.= ''; }'"><a href="';
```

This peice of code (below), that you saw above I got from the same file. It was used like this to detect if its a sub category and add a count, i was thinking i could use it or modify slightly to detect if it a sub category and add a class.

```
if (tep_has_category_subcategories($counter)) {

    $categories_string .= '';

  }
```

I guess it would be helpful to show the full php file, pasted below ( i marked the line i am trying to edit with  /******THIS IS THE LINE I AM TRYING EDIT********/:

```
<?php

class bm_categories {

var $code = 'bm_categories';

var $group = 'boxes';

var $title;

var $description;

var $sort_order;

var $enabled = false;



function bm_categories() {

  $this->title = MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_TITLE;

  $this->description = MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION;



  if ( defined('MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS') ) {

    $this->sort_order = MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_SORT_ORDER;

    $this->enabled = (MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS == 'True');



    $this->group = ((MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_CONTENT_PLACEMENT == 'Left Column') ? 'boxes_column_left' : 'boxes_column_right');

  }

}



function tep_show_category($counter) {

  global $tree, $categories_string, $cPath_array;

  for ($i=0; $i<$tree[$counter]['level']; $i++) {

    //$categories_string .= "&nbsp;&nbsp;";

  }

 /******THIS IS THE LINE I AM TRYING EDIT********/ $categories_string .= '<li><a href="';


  if ($tree[$counter]['parent'] == 0) {

    $cPath_new = 'cPath=' . $counter;

  } else {

    $cPath_new = 'cPath=' . $tree[$counter]['path'];

  }

  $categories_string .= tep_href_link(FILENAME_DEFAULT, $cPath_new) . '">';



  if (isset($cPath_array) && in_array($counter, $cPath_array)) {

    $categories_string .= '<strong>';

  }


 // display category name

  $categories_string .= $tree[$counter]['name'];



  if (isset($cPath_array) && in_array($counter, $cPath_array)) {

    $categories_string .= '</strong>';

  }



  if (tep_has_category_subcategories($counter)) {

    $categories_string .= '';

  }

    if (SHOW_COUNTS == 'true') {

    $products_in_category = tep_count_products_in_category($counter);

    if ($products_in_category > 0) {

      $categories_string .= '<span class="mj-countcolor">&nbsp;(' . $products_in_category . ')</span>';

    }

  }

  $categories_string .= '</a></li>';





  if ($tree[$counter]['next_id'] != false) {

    $this->tep_show_category($tree[$counter]['next_id']);

  }

}



function getData() {

  global $categories_string, $tree, $languages_id, $cPath, $cPath_array;



  $categories_string = '';

  $tree = array();



  $categories_query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where c.parent_id = '0' and c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id='" . (int)$languages_id ."' order by sort_order, cd.categories_name");

  while ($categories = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query))  {

    $tree[$categories['categories_id']] = array('name' => $categories['categories_name'],

                                                'parent' => $categories['parent_id'],

                                                'level' => 0,

                                                'path' => $categories['categories_id'],

                                                'next_id' => false);



    if (isset($parent_id)) {

      $tree[$parent_id]['next_id'] = $categories['categories_id'];

    }



    $parent_id = $categories['categories_id'];



    if (!isset($first_element)) {

      $first_element = $categories['categories_id'];

    }

  }



  if (tep_not_null($cPath)) {

    $new_path = '';

    reset($cPath_array);

    while (list($key, $value) = each($cPath_array)) {

      unset($parent_id);

      unset($first_id);

      $categories_query = tep_db_query("select c.categories_id, cd.categories_name, c.parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " c, " . TABLE_CATEGORIES_DESCRIPTION . " cd where c.parent_id = '" . (int)$value . "' and c.categories_id = cd.categories_id and cd.language_id='" . (int)$languages_id ."' order by sort_order, cd.categories_name");

      if (tep_db_num_rows($categories_query)) {

        $new_path .= $value;

        while ($row = tep_db_fetch_array($categories_query)) {

          $tree[$row['categories_id']] = array('name' => $row['categories_name'],

                                               'parent' => $row['parent_id'],

                                               'level' => $key+1,

                                               'path' => $new_path . '_' . $row['categories_id'],

                                               'next_id' => false);



          if (isset($parent_id)) {

            $tree[$parent_id]['next_id'] = $row['categories_id'];

          }



          $parent_id = $row['categories_id'];



          if (!isset($first_id)) {

            $first_id = $row['categories_id'];

          }



          $last_id = $row['categories_id'];

        }

        $tree[$last_id]['next_id'] = $tree[$value]['next_id'];

        $tree[$value]['next_id'] = $first_id;

        $new_path .= '_';

      } else {

        break;

      }

    }

  }



  $this->tep_show_category($first_element);



  $data = '<div class="ui-widget infoBoxContainer mj-categoriessidebox">' .

          '  <div class="ui-widget-header infoBoxHeading">' . MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_BOX_TITLE . '</div>' .

          '  <div class="ui-widget-content infoBoxContents"><ul>
          <li><a href="/products_new.php">What\'s New?</a></li>
          <li><a href="/specials.php">Specials</a></li>


          '. $categories_string .'</ul></div>' .

          '</div>';



  return $data;

}



function execute() {

  global $SID, $oscTemplate;



  if ((USE_CACHE == 'true') && empty($SID)) {

    $output = tep_cache_categories_box();

  } else {

    $output = $this->getData();

  }



  $oscTemplate->addBlock($output, $this->group);

}



function isEnabled() {

  return $this->enabled;

}



function check() {

  return defined('MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS');

}



function install() {

  tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, set_function, date_added) values ('Enable Categories Module', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS', 'True', 'Do you want to add the module to your shop?', '6', '1', 'tep_cfg_select_option(array(\'True\', \'False\'), ', now())");

  tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, set_function, date_added) values ('Content Placement', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_CONTENT_PLACEMENT', 'Left Column', 'Should the module be loaded in the left or right column?', '6', '1', 'tep_cfg_select_option(array(\'Left Column\', \'Right Column\'), ', now())");

  tep_db_query("insert into " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " (configuration_title, configuration_key, configuration_value, configuration_description, configuration_group_id, sort_order, date_added) values ('Sort Order', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_SORT_ORDER', '0', 'Sort order of display. Lowest is displayed first.', '6', '0', now())");

}



function remove() {

  tep_db_query("delete from " . TABLE_CONFIGURATION . " where configuration_key in ('" . implode("', '", $this->keys()) . "')");

}



function keys() {

  return array('MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_STATUS', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_CONTENT_PLACEMENT', 'MODULE_BOXES_CATEGORIES_SORT_ORDER');

    }

  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, this i what I figured out to make it add the clas to sub categories....

```
$categories_string .= '<li class="';

if ($tree[$counter]['level'] == 1) {
$categories_string .= 'sub';
}

$categories_string .= '"><a href="';
```

and then as @Ghost pointed out, the shorter code would be..

```
$categories_string .= '<li class="' . ($tree[$counter]['level'] == 1 ? 'sub' : '') . '"><a href="';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$categories_string .= '<li class="';

if (tep_has_category_subcategories()) {
    $categories_string .= '';
}

$categories_string .= '"><a href="';
```

Or, using a second variable `$class`:

```
if (tep_has_category_subcategories()) {
    $class = 'xyz';
}
else {
    $class = '';
}

$categories_string .= "<li class='$class'><a href='";
```

Comment: thanks for your fast answer. The first example makes every item in the list have the class regardless of it its a subcategory or not . _ I guess it's my fault perhaps I am using the wrong snippet to to this. Your second example made the list break.

Comment: However, i can now see the syntax a bit better thanks for your help

Comment: I have pasted the full file above now - any ideas to achieve what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could also use a ternary operator in this case:

```
$categories_string .= '<li class="'.(tep_has_category_subcategories() ? 'hello_class' : '').'"><a href="';
```

Further explanation:

It works the same way as this:

```
$class = '';
if(tep_has_category_subcategories()) {
    $class = 'sub';
}

$categories_string .= "<li class='$class'><a href='";
```

So:

```
(tep_has_category_subcategories() ? 'hello_class' : '')
   ^ if this function is true         do this  /else ^ do this
```

Comment: makes every item in the list have the class regardless of it its a subcategory or not . _ I guess it's my fault perhaps I am using the wrong snippet to to this.
nice short code though :)

Comment: I have pasted the full file above now - any ideas to achieve what i am trying to do?

Comment: @BillOfUK if have seen the part where you intent to put it, i don't understand, is that really what you're trying to do? where the function `tep_has_category_subcategories()` returns true, you want to concatenate an empty string? `.= '';`?

Comment: Instead of the empty string... i will put a name of a class e.g: 'sub' - I want all sub categories to have class='sub'

Comment: @BillOfUK sidenote: are you sure that is the correct way of using that function? maybe you need to pass a parameter `tep_has_category_subcategories($post_id)` or something

Comment: Guess it could work the other way too.. like if its NOT a parent category...
I wish i could understand code better :(

Comment: I am not sure at all.

Comment: @BillOfUK is this a osCommerce? it seems you need to pass a `tep_has_category_subcategories($category_id)` in there

Comment: Thanks, yes oscommerce. I think you are right i am using the wrong function :(

Comment: @BillOfUK here is the reference http://www.oscdox.com/crossx/includes/functions/general.php.source.html#l396

Comment: I tried it like this but its still adding the class to all categories even if they are not a sub category
    $categories_string .= '<li class="'.(tep_has_category_subcategories($category_id) ? 'sub' : '').'"><a href="';

Comment: @BillOfUK well, since i can't see the database table schema and its contents, i won't be able to debug on this side. that function has a query inside: here take a look http://pastebin.com/xRyKw26m

Comment: OK, many thanks for your answers anyway... i think this function is only used for counting.

Comment: @BillOfUK no what it means is that when `count()` is greater than zero, (rows found, then it return `true`, if no rows where found pertaining to that category id then it returns `false`. anyway, i hope it turns out well for you at some point, im glad this helped in some way.

Comment: I just managed to get something to work :) using the level function found in the same file e.g:
`$categories_string .= '<li class="';

if ($tree[$counter]['level'] == 1) {
    $categories_string .= 'sub';
}

$categories_string .= '"><a href="';

Comment: @BillOfUK wow glad you made a workaround instead of forcing to use that function lol. then you can apply the ternary `$categories_string .= '<li class="' . ($tree[$counter]['level'] == 1 ? 'sub' : '') . '"><a href="'; `